# How does a PersistenceFacility using Castle.Windsor affect my ability to implement an NHibernateActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, castle, sessionfactory

Questions a bit vague sorry. I wired up a new project with NHibernate and Castle Windsor using a tutorial. The result was a PersistenceInstaller and a PersistenceFacility. The PersistenceFacility has an Init() method like this:

```
    protected override void Init()
    {
        var config = BuildDatabaseConfiguration();

        Kernel.Register(
            Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(_ => config.BuildSessionFactory()),
            Component.For<ISession>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
```

I came across Ayendes solution to managing sessions [Here](http://ayende.com/blog/4808/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-getting-rid-of-globals) - in his series "refactoring towards frictionless and odorless code". Now, currently the [PersistenceFacility](http://pastebin.com/y6YP1zAR) is responsible for creating the SessionFactory. I'm wondering how I might be able to refactor things around (or if that's even necessary) so I can implement the [NHibernateActionFilter](http://pastebin.com/GjppGNbX) - which currently requires access to the SessionFactory in the line:

```
sessionController.Session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
```

Maybe I'm not understanding Castle.Windsor properly, I'm not really sure. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it, bit of an obvious one if so. Prying myself away from the screen and having a walk to the shop helped! I should just inject the ISessionFactory into the NHibernateActionFilter right?

```
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public NHibernateActionFilter(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```